# Regex with whole word and optional first character

Tags: regex

Let's say I'm searching for the whole word, "cat", but not "catastrophy" or "copycat". I can do that with the expression

```
/\bcat\b/\i
```

What if (I'm searching through tweets, by the way) I want to also match "#cat" or "@cat"?

What's the cleanest regex to accomplish this?

Comment: hacked attempts with /\[#@]cat\b/i ... I'm a regex novice

Comment: And what happened when you tried that regex?

Comment: @jnunn: You need to put the `\b` *after* the `([@#])?`, since otherwise the `@` or `#` would only be included if it's immediately preceded by a word character.

Comment: What do you want matched in `The pussy-cat and the tom-cat have normal cats’ tails, but the the manx cat’s tail is missing.` As you see, I’m thinking of English-language words not program-identifier words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write either of these:

```
/(?:\b|[#@])cat\b/i

/[#@]?\bcat\b/i
```

which will match either `cat` as a whole word, or else `#` or `@` plus `cat` as a whole word. (They're equivalent; you can use whichever one you find clearer.)

*(Note: you don't mention which regex engine you're using, so the above is an educated guess based on the information you did provide.)*

Comment: I think I may prefer the second of your two solutions; it seems simpler to understand, although it does require that people actually understand `\b` correctly, which many and probably most do not.

Answer (score 1):

Another guess `/^[@#]?\bcat\b`:

```
 echo "#cat" | perl -ne 'print if /^[@#]?\bcat\b/i'
 #cat

 echo "@cat" | perl -ne 'print if /^[@#]?\bcat\b/i'
 @cat
```

but not:

```
 echo "~cat" | perl -ne 'print if /^[@#]?\bcat\b/i'
```

(Note the ^ as the difference to the other posting.)

Regards